# How do I add multiple horizontal lines in CSS using the <hr> element?

Tags: html, css

I have already successfully added 1 horizontal line, but when I try to add another one (by using multiple `<hr>` elements in the HTML), it doesn't seem to work.

HTML Code:
`<hr/>`

CSS code:

```
hr {   
   width: 90%;    
   height: 7px;    
   margin-left: 50px;    
   margin-right: auto; 
   background-color: #911637;    
   border: 0 none;    
   position: absolute;    
   top: 110px; 
   right: 85px;    
   left: 0px;    
   down: 0px;
}
```

---

Comment: Do you definitely need the lines to be in the DOM rather than drawn as background images? And how is their positioning decided?

Answer (score 0):

**first:**, for position, use `top` `right` `left` and `bottom` not `done`

**second:**, the reason why the second `<hr/>` isn't showing is bcs it's on top of the first one, due to using absolute position

here is a link for small demo where you can see the code 
[codepen demo](https://codepen.io/monkeysalater/pen/qBxvyYx)

Comment: This helps alot! And how do I make one line look different from the other one, since both are assigned the <hr/> value?

Comment: you wanna watch some HTML/CSS tutorial. the basic idea is to assign each different selector which you can reference in yoou CSS file. 

if you liked the answer, like it.